# Not getting expected output:getting infinite while loop

Tags: python-3.x

When input is 245 it should give 200 40 5.Its giving 0 45 for infinite times.Whats wrong with the code

```
    input1=int(input("Enter num "))
    n=len(str(input1))
    while(n>=1):
       unit_place=10**(int(n)-1)
       div=int(input1/unit_place)
       rem=input1%unit_place
       print(div*unit_place,rem)
       input1=rem
```

Comment: This will be an infinite loop. Use n -=1 after input1

Comment: Iam not getting it.can u explain plz

Comment: while condition has `n>=1`. The current value of `n` is 3. You are never decrementing it. It will be always `>=1`(i.e. an infinite loop).

Comment: @triandicAnt I thought **n=len(str(rem))** n will give the length of rem automatically so i did not include **n** in while loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input1=int(input("Enter num "))
n=len(str(input1))
list=[]
print("div*unit_place |","rem")
while(n>=1):
  unit_place=10**(int(n)-1)
  div=int(input1/unit_place)
  rem=input1%unit_place
  list.append(div*unit_place)
  print(str(div*unit_place)+" |",rem)
  input1=rem
  n=int(n)-1
print(list)
```

Output

```
Enter num  245
div*unit_place | rem
200            | 45
40             | 5
5              | 0
[200, 40, 5]
```

Comment: what happens if **n = len(str(input1))** is not included in while loop??.I thought when input1 gets updated **n** will return the length of rem.Why is it not working like that??

Answer (score 2):

Doing some cleanup on your code as:

#### Code:

```
input1=int(input("Enter num "))
n = len(str(input1))
results = []
while n > 1:
    unit_place = 10 ** (int(n) - 1)
    div, rem = divmod(input1, unit_place)
    results.append(div * unit_place)
    input1 = rem
    n = len(str(input1))
results.append(rem)
print(results)
```

#### Results for 245:

```
[200, 40, 5]
```

Comment: what happens if  **n = len(str(input1))** is not included in while loop??..Do we have to include all variables inside any loop which we want to get updated automatically??

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
input1=int(input("Enter num "))
n=len(str(input1))
while(n>=1):
   unit_place=10**(int(n)-1)
   div=int(input1/unit_place)
   rem=input1%unit_place
   print(div*unit_place,rem)
   input1=rem
   n -=1
```

Output:

```
Enter num 123
100 23
20 3
3 0
```

And if you want the output in the way you mentioned , use:

```
input1=int(input("Enter num "))
n=len(str(input1))
while(n>=1):
   unit_place=10**(int(n)-1)
   div=int(input1/unit_place)
   rem=input1%unit_place
   print(div*unit_place, end =" ")
   input1=rem
   n -=1
```

Output:

```
Enter num 123
100 20 3
```

Comment: I thought when input1 gets updated **n** will return the length of **rem**.Why is it not working like that??.Sometimes the varibles dont get updated when i use loops.

Comment: If you want like that , you will have to use the line - n = len(str(input1)) in place of n -=1. As, that line is outside while loop, so we have to define it inside loop so that it gets updated each time.

Comment: Thank you so muchh...So whenever we need any number of  variable outside the loop to update automatically we have to define it inside the loop ryt?

Comment: Yes, you will have to mention the condition inside loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I learned half of coding techniques in stack overflow.